# Bayes Theorem Probability with 3 events

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am having trouble understanding how to set this one up, I don't need the full answer just how to set it up.

> Sally is always running late to campus. The probability she is late to campus for when she uses her moped is $3\%$, for her car $10\%$ and then the train is $7\%$. 
> **Question**: Say the probability that Sally uses her moped is $0.7$, car $0.2$ , or train $0.1$. What is the probability Sally ends up being late? Please use extended Bayes Theorem.

My mistake, miss typed a number

Comment: For me to attack the problem, usage of the car, train, &/or moped need to be mutually exclusive events.  0.7 + 0.2 + 0.6 is not equal to 1.  Perhaps someone else can attack this problem under the assumption that she may use (for example) moped + train (putting the moped in the freight compartment of the train).  But if she does use more than one conveyance, how does that affect probability that she will be late.  Alternative approach is to assume (**blindly**) that one should **scale** the numbers down proportionally, so that they add up to 1.  ...see next comment

Comment: Best approach would be for OP to edit query to resolve issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_1$ be the event: Sally uses her moped

Let $A_2$ be the event: Sally uses her car

Let $A_3$ be the event: Sally uses the train

Let $B$ be the event: Sally is late

Using total probability formula:

$P(B) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(B|A_i)P(A_i) = P(B|A_1)P(A_1) + P(B|A_2)P(A_2) + P(B|A_3)P(A_3)$